# How to loop inside a json file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I have a json file returned on my javascript code. The file looks like this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "594984240522886",
            "from": {
                "id": "593959083958735",
                "category": "Community",
                "name": "Decoc"
            },
            "name": "Ducks",
            "description": "ducks",
            "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=594984240522886&id=593959083958735&aid=1073741834",
            "cover_photo": "594984260522884",
            "count": 4,
            "type": "normal",
            "created_time": "2013-06-13T15:12:22+0000",
            "updated_time": "2013-06-13T15:12:40+0000",
            "can_upload": false
        },
        {
            "id": "593963787291598",
            "from": {
                "id": "593959083958735",
                "category": "Community",
                "name": "Decoc"
            },
            "name": "Profile Pictures",
            "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=593963787291598&id=593959083958735&aid=1073741832",
            "cover_photo": "593963797291597",
            "count": 1,
            "type": "profile",
            "created_time": "2013-06-11T16:52:29+0000",
            "updated_time": "2013-06-11T16:52:31+0000",
            "can_upload": false
        },
        {
            "id": "593963467291630",
            "from": {
                "id": "593959083958735",
                "category": "Community",
                "name": "Decoc"
            },
            "name": "Goats",
            "description": "goats",
            "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=593963467291630&id=593959083958735&aid=1073741831",
            "cover_photo": "593963477291629",
            "count": 7,
            "type": "normal",
            "created_time": "2013-06-11T16:51:56+0000",
            "updated_time": "2013-06-11T16:52:02+0000",
            "can_upload": false
        },
        {
            "id": "593962700625040",
            "from": {
                "id": "593959083958735",
                "category": "Community",
                "name": "Decoc"
            },
            "name": "Dogs",
            "description": "dogs",
            "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=593962700625040&id=593959083958735&aid=1073741830",
            "cover_photo": "593962710625039",
            "count": 10,
            "type": "normal",
            "created_time": "2013-06-11T16:50:27+0000",
            "updated_time": "2013-06-11T16:50:37+0000",
            "can_upload": false
        },
        {
            "id": "593961937291783",
            "from": {
                "id": "593959083958735",
                "category": "Community",
                "name": "Decoc"
            },
            "name": "Cows",
            "description": "Cows",
            "link": "http://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=593961937291783&id=593959083958735&aid=1073741829",
            "cover_photo": "593961983958445",
            "count": 5,
            "type": "normal",
            "created_time": "2013-06-11T16:48:26+0000",
            "updated_time": "2013-06-11T16:49:32+0000",
            "can_upload": false
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "after": "NTkzOTYxOTM3MjkxNzgz",
            "before": "NTk0OTg0MjQwNTIyODg2"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to loop inside the "data" and see how many different data elements exist(as you see each element has an id , from , name , description..) . How can i do that with javascript?

Comment: https://www.google.fr/search?q=manipulate+json

Comment: Look at the `length` property of the "data" array.

Comment: What is the main json object name ? you can loop thru using for loop this :
for(i=0; i<jsonObj.data.length; i++)

Comment: Thank you very much mikez302. Thats indeed what i needed. I was thinking about making foreach loops but this one is 100 times cleaner.

Comment: Thank you too Ani , thats the next step for getting specific elements from every "Data" member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
for(i=0;json.data.length;i++){
    var element = json.data[i];
}
```

or also in this other way:

```
for (i in json.data) {
    if (json.data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var element = json.data[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `if (json.data.hasOwnProperty(i))` ? Your `for` statement already assign the right value in the `i` variable, so you don't have to perform check, it will always be true.

Comment: Using `for ... in` with arrays is generally a bad practice.  There is no guarantee that you will get the elements in array order.  `Array.forEach` however, would be a good choice.

Comment: @DaFunix - `hasOwnProperty` is used to filter out anything that has been been monkey-patched into the `Array.prototype`.  For instance, if there was a shim to add a `forEach` or `indexOf` method.